# Laravel 5.2 Authentication,Session,Middleware with postgres database

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I am Completely new to Laravel

Is there any tutorial regarding Basic authentication with laravel 5.2 with postgres. i have seen many tutorials with Mysql. 
I Have tried Auth with middleware in mysql it works fine but in Postgres  Database

I need step by step process implementing authentication middleware and session examples.

Thanx in Advance!!

Comment: Difference between database systems are really handled by Laravel. Laravel makes connecting with databases and running queries extremely simple across a variety of database back-ends using either raw SQL, the fluent query builder, and the Eloquent ORM. You just set `postgres` as driver of database system, and work with models.

Comment: If you have a specific problem in configuration or using it, you can ask it clearly.